# Asked to install certificate after outlook is started

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-sbs-2008

In my company I recently installed a second server (Windows 2012 r2) in addition to the existing Windows SBS 2008 Server, which was also hosting the Exchange server. Then I switched to Office 365 and turned the Exchange Feature off. However, Since about two weeks, the clients are asked to install a certificate from the SBS Server (wich expired in 2013) when Outlook is started.

Is there a way to stop the certificate asking to be installed?

Comment: Are the old exchange accounts still configured? Outlook may be trying to sync them with the old server, which is presenting the certificate.

Comment: I actually don't know. I use the Office 365 sync tool. So I assume the old accounts are still configured, as I didn't delete them. How would I check that?

Comment: It's been a very long time since I had access to an outlook client... I'm sure that's available through the menus, but I won't be able to give you the exact entry. You will get to a window with a list of mail accounts which you can then reconfigure or delete...

Comment: Make sure you have followed the exchange on premise to office 365 migration guide which includes removing the exchange SCP from active directory and updating the autodiscover records. Sounds like Outlook is still connecting to the on premise exchange server for something.

Comment: The SCP configuration did the trick. I ran the command `Set-ClientAccessServer –Identity "ServerName" -AutoDiscoverServiceInternalUri $null` on the server and now it works fine.